# how to get values from views.py and use it in Javascript tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, html

This is my `views.py`

```
def list_note(request): 
    note_info = Note.objects.filter(id_teacher__exact=request.user.id).select_related()

    actual_date = date.today()
    for notes in note_info:
        note_date = notes.remind.date()
        tmp = actual_date + timedelta(days=3)
        note_expired_list = []
        if tmp == note_date:
            print()
        else:
            note_expired_list.append(notes)

    print(note_expired_list)

    note_data = {
        "note_details": note_info,
        "note_expired_list_details": note_expired_list,
    }

    return render_to_response('list_note.html', note_data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want use value `note_expired_list_details` in `<scrpit>` tag to display this in `alert`. How do this?

I try use `{{ note_expired_list_details}}` but in `<script>` tag not work.

This is a part of my templates (I try finding HTML element by Id in JS)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
    <div >
        {% for details in note_expired_list_details %}
            <p>{{ details }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            alert("Test\n" + x[1].childNodes.nodeValue + "\n");
        </script>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Add your template with your javascript code please

Comment: which version of django are you using?

Comment: Django 1.8.4, Python 2.7.9

Comment: Is your javascript code being rendered through Django, or do you have it as a separate .js file?

Comment: Is rendered through Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store value of `{{ note_expired_list_details }}` in a JS variable and then use it however you want?

```
<script>
    var expiredList = '{{ note_expired_list_details }}';

    alert(expiredList);
</script>
```

Comment: Not work like that. Console return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

Comment: @user3618304 Sorry about that. You need to put `{{ note_expired_list_details }}` in quotes like - `'{{ note_expired_list_details }}'`. I've fixed the code in the answer above.